# Update task owner by case owner

Tags: queue

I have a requirement that when the case owner is changed from queue to user need to updated all related task owner with case owner. How can I achieve it using process builder. I am not able to get the reference to Queue id from process builder. Do anyone have any idea to solve it out.

Comment: Have you looked at these links? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71036/how-to-assign-new-object-to-a-queue-using-process-builder-without-using-the-que AND https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cCToAAM

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, your problem is that you cannot set the criteria for your process to fire when the case owner is changed from a queue to a user?

Since the [Record ID Prefix](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005995&language=en_US) for Queues is "00G", you could define the criteria for your action group to:

```
BEGINS(PRIORVALUE([Case].OwnerId), "00G")
```

You can then add that the new OwnerId needs to start with "005" (since it needs to be a user), and then add an action to update all related tasks.